# Can we say If q is incongruent to p modulo n then $q\equiv -p$ (mod n)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Am I right to write:

If q is incongruent to p modulo n, then $q\equiv -p$ (mod n)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The relation $q\equiv -p \pmod{n}$ means that $p + q\equiv 0\pmod{n}$. To say that $q$ is inequivalent to $p$ means that $q\not\equiv p\pmod{n}$; here, $q$ could be any of the $n-1$ values aside from $p\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

`3` is not cong. to `-1` mode `6` and `3` is not cong. to `+1` mode `6`.

Comment: how about if I add this assumption: p&q are distinct prime number and $(p,n)=1=(q,n)$?

Comment: @Jestem:`p=2,q=13,n=3`.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Comment: Btw, I found an special case satisfy this condition which is n=4.

Comment: @Jestem: We are not allowed to proof any claims in Mathematics just by examples. :-)

Comment: Hi, B.S.! I love the image on your profile!

Comment: @amWhy: Hi Amy. Thanks for saying so my friend. Have a good dream right now. ;-)